VsCode Karma DEBUG RUNNER freezes if there's a breakpoint
This problem only just started recently, and I work on a shared project so I'm not sure what might have happened that could have caused this.
However when unit testing our angular project, I can run an ng test just fine
I have a launch json that runs, and used to work perfectly fine even with a breakpoint.
However, if I put a breakpoint anywhere on it, it hangs, and does not complete. My karma DEBUG RUNNER hangs like the attached picture, the debug console is empty, and if I were to click the refresh button on the call stack in vs code, it will not do anything.
enter image description here
Does anyone know why this might be the case?
My current launch json is this, it was working until recently
{
    "name": "ng test",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "trace": true,
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack:///*": "*",
        "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
    }
}


I also started to have this issue latelly, I dont know how to fix.. the solution i found was running
ng test --browsers=Chrome --source-map=true

and then debug in the chrome dev tools
